# Running NSwag without bootstrapping entire site

Tags: asp.net-core, nswag

We are using NSwag to generate swagger files using a command like this:

`node_modules/.bin/nswag run foobar.nswag /runtime:NetCore31`

This seems to actually start the application, and some of our bootstrapping code will fail because the process generating the swagger docs does not have access to connection strings etc.

Is there a way to generate the docs without bootstrapping/starting the entire application?

Is there a way to detect "swagger generation mode" in the startup code, so we could skip steps for that scenario?

Using the `NSwag.AspNetCore` nuget package version `13.11.3`

The `foobar.nswag` file:

```
{
  "runtime": "NetCore31",
  "defaultVariables": null,
  "documentGenerator": {
    "aspNetCoreToOpenApi": {
      "project": "Foobar.csproj",
      "msBuildProjectExtensionsPath": null,
      "configuration": null,
      "runtime": null,
      "targetFramework": null,
      "noBuild": false,
      "msBuildOutputPath": null,
      "verbose": true,
      "workingDirectory": null,
      "requireParametersWithoutDefault": false,
      "apiGroupNames": [
        "BACKEND"
      ],
      "defaultPropertyNameHandling": "Default",
      "defaultReferenceTypeNullHandling": "Null",
      "defaultDictionaryValueReferenceTypeNullHandling": "NotNull",
      "defaultResponseReferenceTypeNullHandling": "NotNull",
      "generateOriginalParameterNames": true,
      "defaultEnumHandling": "Integer",
      "flattenInheritanceHierarchy": false,
      "generateKnownTypes": true,
      "generateEnumMappingDescription": false,
      "generateXmlObjects": false,
      "generateAbstractProperties": false,
      "generateAbstractSchemas": true,
      "ignoreObsoleteProperties": false,
      "allowReferencesWithProperties": false,
      "excludedTypeNames": [],
      "serviceHost": null,
      "serviceBasePath": null,
      "serviceSchemes": [],
      "infoTitle": "My Title",
      "infoDescription": null,
      "infoVersion": "1.0.0",
      "documentTemplate": null,
      "documentProcessorTypes": [],
      "operationProcessorTypes": [],
      "typeNameGeneratorType": null,
      "schemaNameGeneratorType": null,
      "contractResolverType": null,
      "serializerSettingsType": null,
      "useDocumentProvider": false,
      "documentName": "v1",
      "aspNetCoreEnvironment": "Development",
      "createWebHostBuilderMethod": null,
      "startupType": null,
      "allowNullableBodyParameters": true,
      "output": "foobar-swagger.json",
      "outputType": "Swagger2",
      "newLineBehavior": "Auto",
      "assemblyPaths": [],
      "assemblyConfig": null,
      "referencePaths": [],
      "useNuGetCache": false
    }
  },
  "codeGenerators": {
    "openApiToTypeScriptClient": {
      "className": "{controller}Client",
      "moduleName": "",
      "namespace": "",
      "typeScriptVersion": 2.7,
      "template": "Fetch",
      "promiseType": "Promise",
      "httpClass": "HttpClient",
      "withCredentials": false,
      "useSingletonProvider": false,
      "injectionTokenType": "OpaqueToken",
      "rxJsVersion": 6.0,
      "dateTimeType": "Date",
      "nullValue": "Undefined",
      "generateClientClasses": false,
      "generateClientInterfaces": false,
      "generateOptionalParameters": false,
      "exportTypes": true,
      "wrapDtoExceptions": false,
      "exceptionClass": "ApiException",
      "clientBaseClass": null,
      "wrapResponses": false,
      "wrapResponseMethods": [],
      "generateResponseClasses": true,
      "responseClass": "SwaggerResponse",
      "protectedMethods": [],
      "configurationClass": null,
      "useTransformOptionsMethod": false,
      "useTransformResultMethod": false,
      "generateDtoTypes": true,
      "operationGenerationMode": "MultipleClientsFromOperationId",
      "markOptionalProperties": true,
      "generateCloneMethod": false,
      "typeStyle": "Class",
      "enumStyle": "Enum",
      "useLeafType": false,
      "classTypes": [],
      "extendedClasses": [],
      "extensionCode": null,
      "generateDefaultValues": true,
      "excludedTypeNames": [],
      "excludedParameterNames": [],
      "handleReferences": false,
      "generateConstructorInterface": true,
      "convertConstructorInterfaceData": false,
      "importRequiredTypes": true,
      "useGetBaseUrlMethod": false,
      "baseUrlTokenName": "API_BASE_URL",
      "queryNullValue": "",
      "useAbortSignal": false,
      "inlineNamedDictionaries": false,
      "inlineNamedAny": false,
      "templateDirectory": null,
      "typeNameGeneratorType": null,
      "propertyNameGeneratorType": null,
      "enumNameGeneratorType": null,
      "checksumCacheEnabled": false,
      "serviceHost": null,
      "serviceSchemes": null,
      "output": null,
      "newLineBehavior": "Auto"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe this depends on your nswag.json and the way you are generating the docs. Could you post your nswag.json?  It would also be useful to know what version of nswag you are using, etc..

Comment: @S.tenBrinke I added some more information :)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  If so, did my answer help? If so, please accept it as the answer. If you found a different solution, please post it as an answer and mark it as accepted. If you still have issues, also let us know! :)

Answer (score 1):

I do not see anything super weird in your nswag.json; perhaps you still need to post your Startup.cs where you configure OpenApi/Swagger.

Do you perhaps do weird things in your `ConfigureServices()` like run specific code that requires specific settings being available like connectionstrings. For example? I believe this is a bad practice. I also believe nswag does kind of run your project/run `ConfigureServices()` (but I am just guessing from memory) so  that could cause issues, yeah.

Otherwise, try the following:

- I personally set `targetFramework` to `net5.0` (you use netcore 3.1 so need a different value) where you leave it empty
- This might be a combination of things:

  - I have `nobuild` set to `false` because I build my project before I run `nswag` because it caused lots of issues randomly with projects not being built correctly when nswag tried to do it or other issues.
  - I do not use a node_module for building the nswag.json. I Use `the nswag.msbuild` package and have it all in a seperate `Api.Client` assembly with the [recommended setup](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/wiki/NSwag.MSBuild).
  - I also use `"configuration": "$(Configuration)"` in my nswag.json.

I just came up with a very ugly solution which you MIGHT use, but I do believe this would be an ugly workaround as I think that your problem lies with using a bad-practice in the ConfigureServices().

The solution would be to to pass another variable to your API when it is starting up, or changing the Environment to `Nswag` or something like that so in your code you could do something like `if(environment != "nswag") {}` but again, ugly..

Comment: I've stumbled into a similar situation in my code, and I do do "weird things" in my ConfigureServices, where I need a connection string to set up a service correctly. You're describing this as a bad practice, which I suppose it might be. But how should I be doing it?

Comment: I suggest you create a new question and perhaps send me a mail/reply to this message with your question link. You could do multiple things. I believe you can generate your nswag in different ways. This way is using the actual assembly and startup and stuff like that, but you can also use just the openapi spec. You can find more on this in the nswag github wiki and in the nswag desktop tool. Furthermore, perhaps we can make the connectionstring bit prettier so it would work, or if not, use an IF statement around the code so you do not execute it when nswag is generating its code. Ugly but works

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit late but this might help someone else. I was facing this same issue (also described here: https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/3922)

I tried the solution to use the `createWebHostBuilderMethod` and `startupType` configurations in nswag.json (described here: https://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2021/05/nswag-error-systeminvalidoperationexcep.html) but that didn't work for me as those configurations seem to be depreciated now.

What worked for me was:

1. Create a custom configuration in my Solution called `NSwag` used only by MyApi project.
2. Create a custom NSwag `Program.cs` and `Startup.cs` in MyApi project using a `NSwag` namespace and a `NSwag` precompiler directive wrapped around both classes. The `Startup` class contains only the bootstrapping required for the Controllers and Swagger and removes all other irrelevant bootstrapping, in particular those that depend on app settings at runtime.
3. Update the main MyApi `Program.cs` to use normal or NSwag bootstrapping by using a precompiler directive.
4. Use the `NSwag` configuration in the nswag.json, i.e. set `configuration` to `NSwag`.

MyApi NSwag Program.cs

```
#if NSWAG
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

namespace MyApi.NSwag;

public class Program
{
    public static void RunHost(string[] args)
    {
        var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();
        host.Run();
    }

    private static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .UseStartup<Startup>(); // MyApi.NSwag.Startup

        return builder;
    }
}
#endif
```

MyApi NSwag Startup.cs

```
#if NSWAG
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace MyApi.NSwag;

public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // i.e. whatever you normally have to bootstrap your controllers and Swagger
        services.AddControllers();

        services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(o =>
            {
                o.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";
                o.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
            })
            .AddApiVersioning(o =>
            {
                o.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
                o.ReportApiVersions = true;
                o.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
                o.ApiVersionReader = new UrlSegmentApiVersionReader();
                o.UseApiBehavior = false;
            });

        services.AddSwaggerDocument(config =>
        {
            config.DocumentName = "allVersions";
            config.Title = "My API";
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseOpenApi();
        app.UseSwaggerUi3();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
    }
}
#endif
```

Main MyApi Program.cs

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

namespace MyApi;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
#if NSWAG
        NSwag.Program.RunHost(args);
#else
        RunHost(args);
#endif
    }

    private static void RunHost(string[] args)
    {
        // i.e. whatever you normally have in Main
        var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();
        host.Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .UseStartup<Startup>(); // MyApi.Startup

        return builder;
    }
}
```

MyApi nswag.json

```
{
    "runtime": "Net60",
    "defaultVariables": null,
    "documentGenerator": {
      "aspNetCoreToOpenApi": {
        "project": "src/MyApi/MyApi.csproj",
        "msBuildProjectExtensionsPath": null,
        "configuration": "NSwag",
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you're using the `Nswag.MsBuild` [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NSwag.MSBuild) in your project, you can have a build step in [your csproj like](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/wiki/NSwag.MSBuild):

```
<Target Name="NSwag" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
  <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(ProjectDir)" EnvironmentVariables="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Nswag" Command="$(NSwagExe_Net50) run nswag.json /variables:Configuration=$(Configuration)" />
</Target>
```

Note the `EnvironmentVariables="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Nswag"` attribute. This allows you check for the value of the 'ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT' environment variable and change your startup logic accordingly:

```
var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");

if (string.Equals(env, "Nswag")) {
  // just for nswag
  return;
}
```

And you don't need to use the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` as your variable name too, it can be anything.